# Binding a Style DataTrigger to a custom ICommand's status property

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have a custom implementation of WPF's `ICommand`, that executes its bindings in a `BackgroundWorker`, so that the UI stays responsive.

I would like to display a custom effect while the bindings are being executed. For now, the effect is simplified to setting command source's `IsEnabled` property to `False`. Later, our designer will come up with some nice progress-style animation.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do, that works (sort of):

```
<Button Width="80"
        Command="{x:Static Member=local:AppCommands.Test}"
        DataContext="{x:Static Member=local:AppCommands.Test}">
  <Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsExecuting, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

As evident, my `ICommand` contains an `IsExecuting` property, which is set to `True` while the `BackgroundWorker` does its thing with the bindings, consequently disabling the button in the UI.

Unfortunately, having to explicitly set the button's `DataContext` to command instance prevents me from referring to the original `DataContext` in cases like this one:

```
<Button Width="80"
        Command="{x:Static Member=local:AppCommands.ParamTest}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}"
        DataContext="{x:Static Member=local:AppCommands.ParamTest}">
```

Here, the `CommandParameter` should bind to the window's `DataContext` (which is set to an instance of my view-model), but instead it binds to the command which knows nothing about `SelectedItem`.

There are probably more ways to solve this, and I'm interested to hear all of them. I myself have been thinking along the lines of using an attached property to replace the direct binding to command's `IsExecute` and with it the need for setting the `DataContext`, but I'm not yet sure how to do that.

Any advice is most welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I've come up with this simple solution:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Command.IsExecuting, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
```

It does what I wanted so I'm happy. If anyone thinks there's a better way, I'm still interested, though.